# Как вывести подрубрики текущей рубрики в Wordpress в сайдбар?

Tags: wordpress

Как вывести подрубрики текущей рубрики в Wordpress в сайдбар?

```
Есть:
- Рубрика
- - Подрубрика
- - - Третий уровень рубрики
```

Мне нужно чтобы на каждой страницы рубрики показывала только подрубрики одним уровнем ниже и то что идёт дальше (третий уровень рубрики) не должно отображаться как это реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Так отталкивайтесь от родителя.

```
$categories=get_categories(
    array( 'parent' => $cat->cat_ID )
);
```